# Data annotations are not regenerated in the class when I reload my model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-database-first

I'm developping a web application linked to a database using MVC Pattern and EF 6.0. To ensure that the datas entered on my web application are correct, I want to use data annotations.

I've followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation) tutorial but I'm currently stuck at the last part.

It's written that:

> Adding the validation attributes directly to the model class works
>   when you do not expect the database to change; however, if your
>   database changes and you need to regenerate the model class, you will
>   lose all of the attributes you had applied to the model class. This
>   approach can be very inefficient and prone to losing important
>   validation rules.
>
> To avoid this problem, you can add a metadata class that contains the
>   attributes. When you associate the model class to the metadata class,
>   those attributes are applied to the model. In this approach, the model
>   class can be regenerated without losing all of the attributes that
>   have been applied to the metadata class.

Therefore I followed the steps creating a metadata class and partial classes.

The last part of the tutorial ask us to refresh the Model which I did.
However by doing so, the data annotations that should be present in my class are nowhere to be found. They were present before the refresh but got erased of my class.

Pre updated/refreshed class is working fine.

Post updated class doesn't seem to apply any restriction , for instance I can insert a new client with an age of 11 even though a value higher than 10 should not be accepted.

This is my class pre-refresh :

```
public partial class TaClient
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TaClient()
    {
        this.TaBracelets = new HashSet<TaBracelet>();
    }

    public int IdClient { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)] //data annotation for FirstName

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)] //data annotation for LastName

    public string Sex { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

    [Range(3,10)] // data annotation for Age
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TaBracelet> TaBracelets { get; set; }
}
```

This is my class post refresh :

```
public partial class TaClient
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TaClient()
    {
        this.TaBracelets = new HashSet<TaBracelet>();
    }

    public int IdClient { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TaBracelet> TaBracelets { get; set; }
}
```

this is my metadata class:

```
public class TaClientMetadata
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName;

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName;

    [Range(3, 10)]
    [Display(Name = "Age")]
    public int Age;
}
```

And this is my partial class :

```
public class PartialClasses
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TaClientMetadata))]
    public partial class TaClient
    {
    }
}
```

I probably miss understood something.

Comment: What do you mean "regenerated"? They aren't generated to begin with. Data annotations are the attributes over your properties. They *don't* need to go on a separate class either. Are you trying to perform validation that fails? Perhaps the UI doesn't update to reflect the type or length specified in the annotations? What UI/stack? WPF, WInforms, MVC ?

Comment: Bit confused. Are you using entity framework as they are in that tutorial?

Comment: Data annotations are *not* specific to Entity Framework, much less the Database First process. You have to explain that you are using EF Database first and refer to the metadata classes

Comment: BTW the metadata class is *not* generated by any wizard, it's written by the developer. That's what the tutorial explains too. Its job is to hold annotations that would be lost when the data classes were regenerated.  If you changed your database model and eg added extra properties or changed field lengths you'll have to update the annotations by hand

Comment: I'm sorry to have you all confused, I'll rewrite my post.

Comment: Note that attributes are attached to the member *after* the attribute. Your empty lines don't change that.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, I didn't change anything in my database I just right click on model ->update->tables. If I have to rewrite everything by hand everytime I refresh, then what is the point of meta data. My english is not that good so maybe I miss understood the goal of creating metadata and partial classes. I though they were here to store the data annotations if I refresh the Model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the original partial class. To do that you need to define *exactly the same* class in *exactly the same* namespace, both of them marked with the `partial` keyword. In the auto-generated code, the `partial` keyword is already present. For your custom partial class definition you have to do this manually:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TaClientMetadata))]
partial class TaClient
{
}
```

This has to be defined directly in the namespace. This, however is not what you are doing. You are defining a nested partial class within *another* class named `PartialClasses`. While this will compile fine, you will end up with two classes: `TaClient` (which is auto-generated) and `PartialClasses.TaClient` (which is created by you).

On a more general note: When you read through tutorials, it is sometimes necessary to familiarize yourself with the underlying concepts. In this case this would be the concept of partial classes.